# Groovy Sql rows

Tags: jdbc, groovy, grails-2.0, groovy-sql

Hello I am trying to get rows using Groovy Sql connection but it returns me records as a List inside a List. The following:

```
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
List<GroovyRowResult> row = sql.rows('select * from user where username=:userName and password=:password, [userName:'groovy',password:'123'])
```

returns the result as `[[return record as map]]`

Any one help me to figure out why the result is a **List inside a List**. How will I get it as a single level List using the **rows** method?

Answer (score 4):

Your results are coming back as a list of maps, not a list of lists. Look at the ':' and ',' chars in the inner part. You can use standard groovy extraction of values from these.

In your case, it looks like you're using a primary key search, so will only return one result, so use [`firstRow`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#firstRow(groovy.lang.GString)) in this case, so that you don't have to extract the single map result from the list.

See the documentation for the [groovy Sql class](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) for examples.

In the more general case where you are returning multiple rows, then your data probably looks like this:

```
[[username:"foo", password:"foopass"], [username:"bar", password:"barpass"]]
```

Assuming the line:

```
def results = sql.rows('select * from user')
```

You can then do things like spread operators:

```
assert results.username == ["foo", "bar"]
assert results.password == ["foopass", "barpass"]
```

or iterate over the results

```
results.each { println it.username }
==> foo
==> bar
```

or use any of the many [Collection functions](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html)

```
println results.collect { "${it.username} -> ${it.password}" }
==> [ "foo -> foopass", "bar -> barpass" ]
```

I think your main issue was not recognising a single map entry in a list.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't return a `List` inside a `List`, it returns a `List` of `Map` with each map containing the columns selected from your select.

So if you want all of the `username`s selected (as a List), you can just do:

```
def usernames = row.username
```

If you just want a single row, you can do:

```
GroovyRowResult row = sql.firstRow('select * from user where username=:userName and password=:password, [userName:'groovy',password:'123'])
```

And then this will effectively just be a map with each `key` being the field name selected, and each `value` being the value of the first row of each field